# "add breakpoint" shortcut doesn't work in xcode 4.3

Tags: xcode4.3

setting breakpoints with the keyboard shortcut (command + \) doesn't work for me. I tried changing the key binding in xcode preferences, but it still doesn't work. it doesn't look like a conflict with another shortcut in the system.
setting a breakpoint with the mouse works fine, only the shortcut doesn't work. did anyone encountere this kind of problem before? it drives me crazy.

Comment: sigh … i want to award the bounty to @http://stackoverflow.com/users/551484/f%c3%a9lix-sim%c3%b5es, but it won't let me award it for 23 hours.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same problem. It was driving me nuts because sometimes the shortcut would work and other times it wouldn't.

After a while I realize that I had another application using the same shortcut. In my case was the 1Password browser extension. So the shortcut on Xcode would work fine until I use the 1Password extension in one of the browsers, and after that only after logging out, or restart, the Xcode shortcut would work again.

I removed the 1Password global shortcut and now Xcode add/remove breakpoint shortcut works fine.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

No the shortcut works perfectly. I suppose it has to do with another shortcut ... to make sure ...

Go to System Preferences --> Keyboards --> Shortcuts

and search